# NSDateFormatter, show same date for all timezones

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application I receive dates as string from server, for example "2016-09-28T16:51:15.000+0700". I use  NSDateFormatter to get NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

And another formatter to get string from NSDate to display it in UI

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
```

It works correctly and shows date and time depending on timezone, but now I have requirement that the application should display same date and time for all timezones and displaying date and time should be equal to date and time from server response. So for example if the application receives "2016-09-28T16:51:15.000+0700" then it should always display it as 9/28/2016, 4:51 PM. How can I do it?  It is possible to achieve it without changing response format for date and time?

Comment: Will all of the strings be in the same timezone (+0700) or can they be in different timezones? If different, will they all be in the same format?

Comment: They can be in different timezones, but they always have same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really want to ignore the time zone information in the received string cut it out for example using regular expression

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-09-28T16:51:15.000+0700";
NSString *truncatedDateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\.\\d+(\\+|-)\\d+"
                                                                      withString:@""
                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, dateString.length)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:truncatedDateString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"M/d/yyyy h:mm a";
NSString *finalDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
NSLog(@"%@", finalDateString); // 9/28/2016 4:51 PM
```